# How can we solve $\sin(ax) + \sin(bx) = y$ exactly for constants $a,b > 0$ and $y\in [-2,2]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, closed-form

How can we find a closed-form expression for $x$ for constants $a,b > 0$ and $y\in [-2,2]$, where $x$ solves the equation

$$y=\sin(ax) + \sin(bx)\text{?}$$

Comment: Taking $a,b$ integers, we get a polynomial equation in $u=e^{ix}$.  Choose $a,b$ so that this polynomial is not solvable in radicals...  Of course, "closed form" might involve operations other than radicals.

Comment: @liam9999: when a/b not rational the solutions are real as well as complex, requiring numerical iteration. Summation two frequency harmonics.

Comment: Substituting, $b=1$ WLOG, $x\to\sin^{-1}(x)$ and then [this way](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x+%2B+1%2F2+i+%28i+x+%2B+sqrt%281+-+x%29+sqrt%281+%2B+x%29%29%5E%28-a%29+-+1%2F2+i+%28i+x+%2B+sqrt%281+-+x%29+sqrt%281+%2B+x%29%29%5Ea%2Cx%3D+-1%2F2+i+t%5E%28-1%2Fa%29+%28-1+%2B+t%5E%282%2Fa%29%29) gives $y=\frac i2(t^{-\frac1a}-t^\frac1a-t+t^{-1})$ which  likely has a Lagrange reversion series solution, but there are many answers and this is a PSQ, so we cannot get this possible solution

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a nice solution to the problem. The following is not a proof of impossibility, but some of my thoughts as to why it probably can't be done. If someone knows about some more rigorous arguments I'd greatly appreciate it if you commented them!

---

So, you're asking to find the inverse function $f^{-1}(x)$ where $f(x) = \sin(ax) + \sin(bx)$ for some $a,b>0$. Taking the substitution $u = ax$ to reduce the number of variables transforms the problem into inverting
$$
f(u) = \sin(u) + \sin(\xi u)
$$
where $ \xi = \frac{b}{a}$ is some constant. It is known that the sine function has inverse function $\arcsin$, thus, if $f(u)=g(\sin(u))$ (i.e. if we can express the function $ \sin(\xi u)$ in terms of only $\sin(u)$) then
$$
f^{-1}(u) = \arcsin\left( g^{-1}(u)\right) 
$$
would be the desired inverse function.

Here's the problem. As far as I know, there's no easy way to express $\sin(\xi u)$ as a function of $\sin(u)$ for a general parameter $\xi$. Even for special values like $\xi$ an odd integer you already have a complicated expression for $\sin(\xi u)$ in terms of $\sin(u)$ given by
$$
\sin(\xi u) = (-1)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}T_n(\sin(u))
$$
where $T_n(x)$ is the [Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials). So even in this special case, the problem would require obtaining the inverse function of the Chebyshev polynomials, which I hope you can appreciate starts getting really complicated.

So if even for special values of $a,b$ (and hence special values of $\xi$) it's already very very complicated to invert the function, I believe there's little to no hope in finding a general solution.

Comment: We have to be more accurate: if we solve an equation, we are looking for the partial inverses.

Answer (score 1):

*Remark*
Using the Laurent series of $\sin$, then reverting, we get
$$
x =
 \frac{1}{a+b}y+{\frac {{a}^{2}-ba+{b}^{2}}{6\, \left( a+b
 \right) ^{3}}}{y}^{3}+{\frac {9\,{a}^{4}-19\,b{a}^{3}+29\,{b}^{2}{a}^
{2}-19\,{b}^{3}a+9\,{b}^{4}}{120\, \left( a+b \right) ^{5}}}{y}^{5}
\\
+{
\frac {225\,{a}^{6}-729\,{a}^{5}b+1513\,{a}^{4}{b}^{2}-1793\,{a}^{3}{b
}^{3}+1513\,{a}^{2}{b}^{4}-729\,a{b}^{5}+225\,{b}^{6}}{5040\, \left( a
+b \right) ^{7}}}{y}^{7}+\dots 
$$
near $y=0$.
Of course, this is not "closed form".

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin(ax)+\sin(bx)=y$$
$$-\frac{1}{2}i(e^{aix}-e^{-aix})-\frac{1}{2}i(e^{bix}-e^{-bix})=y$$
$$-\frac{1}{2}i(e^{aix})^2e^{bix}-\frac{1}{2}ie^{aix}
(e^{bix})^2+\frac{1}{2}ie^{aix}+\frac{1}{2}ie^{bix}=ye^{aix}e^{bix}$$
$$-\frac{1}{2}i(e^{aix})^2e^{bix}-\frac{1}{2}ie^{aix}(e^{bix})^2+\frac{1}{2}ie^{aix}+\frac{1}{2}ie^{bix}-ye^{aix}e^{bix}=0$$

We see, in the general case, this equation is a polynomial equation of more than one algebraically independent monomials ($e^{aix},e^{bix}$) and with no univariate factor. We therefore don't know how to rearrange the equation for $x$ by applying only finite numbers of [elementary functions (operations)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) we can read from the equation.

$x\to -it$:
$$-\frac{1}{2}i(e^{at})^4(e^{bt})^3-\frac{1}{2}i(e^{at})^3(e^{bt})^4+\frac{1}{2}i(e^{at})^3(e^{bt})^2+\frac{1}{2}i(e^{at})^2(e^{bt})^3-y(e^{at})^3(e^{bt})^3=0\tag{1}$$

If $a,b$ are algebraic and linearly independent over the rational numbers, $e^a,e^b$ are algebraically independent according to [Lindemann–Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem). Because equation (1) is an irreducible algebraic equation over the algebraic numbers then, the equation cannot have algebraic solutions $x$ in this case.

If $a,b$ are dependent over the rational numbers, equation (1) can be transformed into an algebraic equation over the algebraic numbers of only one variable and we can use the well known solution theory for such equations. The answer of Robert Lee gives the example of $\xi\in\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

See maximum value returned by $y$ is $2$ , only possible when $sin(ax) = 1  ; sin(bx)=1$
So, $x=\frac{\pi}{2a}and\space x=\frac{\pi}{2b}$ , Similarly $-2$ can be obtained when both the values are $-1$ . $[-2,2]$ are the highest and lowest values $y$ can ever take, hence since there is no domain restriction $x \epsilon (-\infty,\infty)$